# Precise liquid level measurement sensor

Tags: sensor

What kind of sensors are suitable for measuring liquid level accurately? minimum level 2 or 3 millimeter. Ultra Sound sensors are not such precise.
*There are various types of liquids with different densities.

Comment: What's the maximum-minimum level difference?

Comment: 5-20cm min-max level.

Comment: What liquid to you have (water, oil, etc)?  What's the shape and diameter of the tank?  What's your overall application (in general)?  There are many liquid level sensor sensor types ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_sensor) and [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/sensorforum)).  Some of them can achieve the accuracy you desire under, if the conditions are right.

Comment: Medical liquids, tank volume is at most one liter.

Comment: "Medical liquids" is not precise enough.  Optically clear?  Milky?  Chunky?  Viscous?  Hot?  Cold?  Corrosive?  Sterile?  Bio-hazard?  Turbulent/moving?  Shape and dimensions of the tank?

Comment: If the specific gravity is known, you could weigh the tank and its contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to assume the liquid in question has a dielectric constant that is very much greater than the dielectric constant of air. This is the case for many liquids, including all liquids whose major component is water. Many "medical liquids" fall in this category, as people are mostly water too.

I am am going to recommend a capacitive measuring system based on the concept described [Scott Edwards' article "Measure Water Level
Without Getting Wet" (Stamp Applications no 27, 1997)](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece445/stamp/nv_mag/st_ap27.pdf):

[image: basic stamp water level measuring system]

Basically, you put the liquid in a small narrow tube, either as a container or through communicating vessels from a larger reservoir. You apply conductive tape to both sides of the tube. You now have made a capacitor with the liquid as dielectric. Because the dielectric constant of the liquid is much higher than the dielectric constant of air, the capacitance of the system increases with increasing water level. Because of the finite dielectric constant of air, the relation is linear but not strictly speaking proportional.

The good thing about this system is that it's relatively accurate, and the electronics never get anywhere near the liquid.

For your specific case, you are measuring relatively small quantities. If it's acceptable in your application, I would get rid of the reservoir altogether and replace it with a single tube about \$10 cm^2\$ in cross section and one meter long. This should enable you to store 1 liter of fluid while giving you plenty of swing in your capacitor value.

For actually measuring the capacitance, there are many solutions. Here's a few:

- Use a CD4060 as in the basic stamp note.
- Turn the capacitance into a frequency with a schmitt-trigger oscillator.
- Use the cap to make an RC filter, feed it with an AC signal (e.g. a square wave from a microcontroller clock), put the result through a rectifier circuit (using an op-amp based circuit to avoid the diode drop) and measure the resulting average voltage

You can find more circuits to perform the capacitance measurement in the [comments of this blog post I made on the subject of capacitive measurement](http://zerocharactersleft.blogspot.nl/2011/11/pcb-as-capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor.html#more).

Comment: *There are various types of liquids with different densities.

Comment: I presume this should have been a reply to Chris Stratton's comment on using the tank's weight? The method outlined above does not depend directly on density.

Comment: @drxzcl The article link is dead

Comment: @MattKlein I updated the link. Maybe we ought to mirror it somewhere in case it goes "p00f" again.

Comment: For completeness, I'll point out that you can buy pre-made sensor assemblies based on this principle (instead of having to build your own). Just an option to consider.

Comment: @mbrig - can you supply a link?

Comment: @AndreasHD [here's](https://www.ca.endress.com/en/Field-instruments-overview/level-measurement/Capacitance-level-measurement) one company making them I found (I haven't used this company's specific products though). From what I know about this stuff, its likely to be rather expensive... "capacitive level sensing" is the keyword to search for.

Comment: @AndreasHD the purchasable assemblies I've found also seem to all be based on inserting into the liquid, rather than having the liquid flow into it. Its the same capacitive principle but "inside-out".